# How can my Javascript function change the style of an html button

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I'm new to JS

I have a button in my HTML and I want my JavaScript function to change the padding on the button when clicked:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.paddingButton');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  btn.style.padding = "'" + Math.random() * 25 + "em" + "'";
});
```

```html
<button class="paddingButton">Button</button>
```

This doesn't work. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra quotes here that are needed in CSS, but not JS:

```
btn.style.padding = "'" + Math.random() * 25 + "em" + "'";
```

replace it with just the number + "em":

```
btn.style.padding = Math.random() * 25 + "em";
```